# How to check if an index before a list item exists?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of objects with keys `title`, `text` and `title` again:

```
"data": [
        {
          "type": "title",
          "data": "Dashboard"
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "data": "This is your dashboard.."
        },
        {
          "type": "title",
          "data": "Fees"
        },
]
```

I am able to show these key values of key `data` on the screen:

[image]

I want to have a space between `text` and `title` if `title` comes **after** text. So i made an if else statement which substracts the `index` with `1` and check if the previous `index` contains key value `text` and then i want to show a `SizedBox` else i want to show an empty `Container`:

```
if ((json[index - 1]['type'] == "text") 
    
   SizedBox(height: 10)
else 
   Container(),
```

But i get error: `RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..3: -1` 
This means that it also substracts the first index with the key value `title` and that is the reason i get index vallue `-1` back. So my question is how can i show `SizedBox` after `text` and then also resolve the error above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that's easily fixed by checking if the index is not 0, so change it to

```
if (index != 0 && json[index - 1]['type'] == "text")
```